# Bootstrap dropdown menu in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, menu, submenu

I want a dropdown menu like this in Wordpress

```
<div class="dropdown">
                    <li class="dropdown-style" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-hover="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Golfbestemmingen <span class="caret"></span>
                    </li>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

The code i have now

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array('menu' => 'Hoofd Menu','container_class' => 'dropdown','items_wrap' => '%3$s')); ?>
```

Someone who can help me with this?

Comment: Why you have an `<li>`-Tag before starting with your `<ul>`?

Comment: It was a button first

Comment: What do you need help with..

Answer (score 0):

Go and do use Wordpress Bootstrap Master themes to customize bootstrap so all the bootstrap functions will be available without any worries.

You can get it here : https://github.com/320press/wordpress-bootstrap